# How to earn Deputy or Marshal badges when you have over 3,000 reputation?

Tags: discussion, flagging, badges

These [badges](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges) are described:

- Deputy: "Achieved a flag weight of 500 by reviewing and flagging appropriately"
- Marshal: "Achieved a flag weight of 749 by reviewing and flagging appropriately"

My flag weight was 470 when I passed the 3,000 reputation threshold and gained the privilege to [cast close votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions). How is it possible to achieve the Deputy and Marshal badges when I can no longer flag posts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can still flag posts as:

- very low quality (use for posts that are gibberish)
- needs other ♦ moderator attention (use for posts that have something weird going on and needs a ♦ mod to look at)
- spam (use for commercial spam)
- offensive (use for offensive, abusive, or hate speech)

In addition, you can also flag answers as *not an answer*, for posts that do not directly answer the question (e.g. is a comment or a question).

Comment: +1 Most of my flags are on answers, though occasionally I ask to delete a blatantly off-topic question.